# Add custom animation to Bootstrap modal when hiding it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to add a css class containing an animation when dismissing a modal on *hide.bs.modal* but it closes right away. Is there any way to set a timeout on *hide.bs.modal* and then hide the modal?

Here's what I tried

```js
$('#modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#modal').addClass('unslide-left');
  $('.modal-backdrop').addClass('fade-out');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#modal').hide();
  }, 300);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code snippet along with HTML?

Comment: @Regent I've tried `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` and it doen't work

Comment: There is a suggestion to use `return e.preventDefault()` on [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-events).

Comment: The jQuery you've provided is fairly useless without the HTML it's supposed to work on. Could be an issue with your jQuery, your HTML, or both. Please provide all relevant components.